# Why might ZSTD not be supported as the compression wire protocol in Cassandra 4.x?

Tags: cassandra

While digging through the Cassandra sources, I noticed that there's no support for ZSTD as the wire protocol on Cassandra. The only options are LZ4 and Snappy.

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0-rc1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/transport/Compressor.java#L39

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0-rc1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/transport/Compressor.java#L127

There is no support for ZSTD even in the upcoming Cassandra 4.x release. There is however ZSTD-based storage compression available in the 4.x https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-4.0-rc1/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/io/compress/ZstdCompressor.java

While Cassandra is pluggable and it seems rather straightforward to make the patches to add ZSTD support - I'm lost as to why something like this is omitted.

Everything Cassandra related seems to have a fair amount of tribal knowledge associated with it and therefore the curiosity.

Comment: @AlexOtt if you'd know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall trade off is likely to be because the total time to compress, transmit the compressed data, and then decompress with ZSTD is higher than to transmit without compression. For storage however, the lower space requirement justifies the overhead.

Using a tool such as https://quixdb.github.io/squash-benchmark/#transfer-plus-processing lets you run the numbers and explore these for yourself, picking various processor and datasets.

For instance, it shows me that both lz4 and snappy are faster than not compressing, but that the higher overhead of zstd compression isn’t offset by its fast decompression and smaller transfer vs not compressing at all over the wire.